# Como fazer um while com 2 verificações

Tags: php, while

Estou tentando que o while pegue 2 valores para parar mas ele apenas não entra no while, estou iniciando em programação então tentem ajudar de uma forma simples

Objetivo do código: Conseguir o 0 de uma função de 1 grau de maneira dinâmica...

```
<?php 

print("Qual é o expoente de sua função?\n");
$menu = fgets(STDIN);
if ($menu == 1) {
    print("Coloque o valor de A:");
    $a = fgets(STDIN);
    print("Coloque o valor de B:");
    $b = fgets(STDIN);
    $xa = 106000;
    $xb =-102000;
                while($mediaA=0.5 and $mediaB=-0.5){

                    $resultA = $a*$xa+$b;
                    $resultB = $a*$xb+$b;
                    $mediaA = $resultA/2;
                    $mediaB = $resultB/2;
                    $resultmedia = $a*$media+$b;
                    if($mediaA > 0 and $mediaB > 0){
                        $xb = $resultB;
                        $xa = $mediaB;
                    }elseif($resultB<0){
                            $xa = $mediaA;
                            $xb = $mediaB;
                    }elseif($mediaA < 0 and $mediaB < 0) {
                            $xb = $mediaB;
                            $xa = $resultA;
                            }elseif($mediaB>0) {
                            $xa = $mediaB;
                            $xb = $mediaA;
                            }               
                    }
            print($mediaA.$mediaB);                                 
    }
?>
```

Comment: O `and` no PHP embora raro é válido e apenas difere do `&&` em termos de [precedência](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.precedence.php), [referência para o `and`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.logical.php).

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que você não queira fazer uma atribuição e sim uma comparação certo? Se for deve conter "==" no lugar de "=", porque se a atribuição funcionar vai retorna verdadeiro sempre.

```
while($mediaA==0.5 and $mediaB==-0.5){
```